# Using Lombok's logging in Inner classes

Tags: lombok

I am trying to use Lombok's @Slf4j annotation in a inner class, but I get compile time error message ***Illegal static declaration in inner class***. For now I have reverted to not use the @Slf4j annotation in the inner class. Does Lombok have a way to apply the @Slf4j annotation to inner classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can by changing Lombok's configuration.

Lombok by default generates loggers as static fields. Inner classes (if not declared static) are instance members of their owning outer class. Hence is it illegal to declare anything static in inner classes; which is why you get the compile time error message.

But you can configure Lombok to generate loggers as instance fields. The easiest way to configure this is by createing a lombok.config file in the directory where your inner class exists. In this lombok.config file add the following line. `lombok.log.fieldIsStatic = false`. Recompile and your error is gone. For details look at lombok's [configuration page](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) and the "Supported configuration keys" section at the bottom of the [@Log page](https://projectlombok.org/features/log).